# Java - How to read a big file word by word instead of line by line?

Tags: java

I'd like to read the "text8" corpus in Java and reformat some words. The problem is, in this 100MB corpus all words are on one line. So if I try to load it with `BufferedReader` and `readLine`, it takes away too much space at once and can't handle it to separate all the words in one list/array.

So my question: Is it possible in Java to read instead of line by line a corpus, to read it word by word? So for example because all words are on one line, to read for example 100 words per iteration?

Comment: Have you tried the `Scanner` class?

Comment: Use `RandomAccessFile` to read large amount of file.

Answer (score 6):

you can try using `Scanner` and set the delimiter to whatever suits you:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(myFile);
input.useDelimiter(" +"); //delimitor is one or more spaces

while(input.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(input.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the "Character stream" with `FileReader`

Here is the example code from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
      FileReader in = null;
      FileWriter out = null;

      try {
         in = new FileReader("input.txt");
         out = new FileWriter("output.txt");

         int c;
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
         }
      }finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It reads 16 bit Unicode characters. This way it doesnt matter if your text is in one whole line.

Since you're trying to search word by word, you can easy read till you stumble upon a space and there's your word.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `next` method of `java.util.Scanner`

> The `next` method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of Scanner.hasNext returned true.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String a = sc.next();
        String b = sc.next();
        System.out.println("First Word: "+a);
        System.out.println("Second Word: "+b);
        sc.close();
    }
```

**Input :**

Hello Stackoverflow

**Output :**

First Word: Hello

Second Word: Stackoverflow

In your case use `Scanner` for reading the file and then use `scannerobject.next()` method for reading each token(word)

Answer (score -1):

```
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Example.docx")) { 
        ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.009);
        XWPFDocument file   = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));  
        ext = new XWPFWordExtractor(file);  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ext.getText());
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] value = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            for(String v:value) {
                System.out.println(v);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
```